# Can a user navigating to different express routes within a multi-page app use the same socketio socket object across routes?

Tags: express, socket.io

Let's say when a user POSTs to /api/signup or /api/signin in an Express app via ajax and on success, calls var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080').

Now while remaining logged in if the user navigates to say GET /api/list/:listId in the same app and SAME browser tab, i.e. not requiring multiple socket connections, does the user have to call 
io.connect('http://localhost:8080') again when loading /api/list/:listId? Or is there a way to use the same connection across routes, i.e. call io.connect(...) once?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you refresh page or navigate to another page as whole code will be parsed again, thus socket will be disconnected. To get around this in our project we are using single page website.